# RIGHT JOIN in place of subselect - a genuine use case?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, right-join

I have avoided `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, since the same can be achieved using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` if you reorder the tables.

However, recently I have been working with the need to have large numbers of joins, and I often encounter a pattern where a series of `INNER JOIN`s are `LEFT JOIN`ed to a sub select which itself contains many `INNER JOIN`s:

```
SELECT *
FROM       Tab_1 INNER JOIN Tab_2 INNER JOIN Tab_3...
LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
           FROM Tab_4 INNER JOIN Tab_5 INNER JOIN Tab_6....
          )...
```

The script is hard to read. I often encounter sub sub selects. Some are correlated sub-selects and performance across the board is not good (probably not only because of the way the scripts are written).

I could of tidy it up in several ways, such as using common table expressions, views, staging tables etc, but a single `RIGHT JOIN` could remove the need for the sub selects. In many cases, doing so would improve performance.

In the example below, is there a way to replicate the result given by the first two SELECT statements, but using only `INNER` and `LEFT` joins?

```
DECLARE @A TABLE (Id INT)
DECLARE @B TABLE (Id_A INT, Id_C INT)
DECLARE @C TABLE (Id INT)

INSERT @A VALUES (1),(2)
INSERT @B VALUES (1,10),(2,20),(1,20)
INSERT @C VALUES (10),(30)

-- Although we want to see all the rows in A, we only want to see rows in C that have a match in B, which must itself match A
SELECT A.Id, T.Id
FROM
            @A                                      AS A
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *
            FROM        @B AS B
            INNER JOIN  @C AS C ON B.Id_C = C.Id)   AS T ON A.Id = T.Id_A;

-- NB Right join as although B and C MUST match, we only want to see them if they also have a row in A - otherwise null.
SELECT A.Id, C.Id
FROM
            @B  AS B
INNER JOIN  @C  AS C ON B.Id_C = C.Id
RIGHT JOIN  @A  AS A ON B.Id_A = A.Id;
```

Would you rather see the long-winded sub-selects, or a `RIGHT JOIN`, assuming decent comments in each case?

All the articles I have ever read have said pretty much what I think about RIGHT JOINS, that they are unecessary and confusing. Is this case strong enough to break the cultural aversion?

Comment: Right joins are confusing, most people find `main table LEFT JOIN optional data` much easier to get than `optional data RIGHT JOIN main table`. (Once in while I've RIGHT JOIN-ed a calendar table, to get rows also for non-data dates.)

Comment: A hack on join order then? Great question, I am very interested to see answers. Despite being unusual, I would vote for your right join syntax. If something proves itself useful, we might as well learn it.

Comment: @jarlh I agree, but in this case, can `LEFT JOIN` perform the same job?

Comment: `t1 LEFT JOIN t2` gives the same result as `t2 RIGHT JOIN t1` - always!

Comment: @jarlh no argument here; as I say, I have always avoided `RIGHT JOIN` because I agree with you - so you're saying you prefer the sub-select syntax in this case, or am I missing a possible alternative simple solution using just `LEFT` and `INNER` joins?

Comment: Please ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer to this question in the old scripts that I was going through - I came across this syntax which performs the same function as the `RIGHT JOIN` example, using `LEFT JOIN`s (or at least I think it does - it certainly gives the correct results in the example):

```
DECLARE @A TABLE (Id INT)
DECLARE @B TABLE (Id_A INT, Id_C INT)
DECLARE @C TABLE (Id INT)

INSERT @A VALUES (1),(2)
INSERT @B VALUES (1,10),(2,20),(1,20)
INSERT @C VALUES (10),(30)

SELECT
    A.Id, C.Id
FROM
            @A  AS A
LEFT JOIN   @B  AS B
    INNER JOIN  @C  AS C
                ON C.Id = B.Id_C
            ON B.Id_A = A.Id
```

I don't know if there is a name for this pattern, which I have not seen before in other places of work, but it seems to work like a "nested" join, allowing the LEFT JOIN to preserve rows from the later INNER JOIN.

EDIT: I have done some more research and apparently this is an ANSI SQL syntax for nesting joins, but... it does not seem to be very popular!

[Descriptive Article](https://www.navicat.com/en/company/aboutus/blog/1948-nested-joins-explained)

[Relevant Stack Exchange Question and Answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52432/syntax-of-inner-join-nested-inside-outer-join-vs-query-results)

Comment: High Plains Grifter - You need parenthesis around the nested joins to properly group them: `FROM @A AS A LEFT JOIN ( @B AS B INNER JOIN @C AS C ON C.Id = B.Id_C ) ON B.Id_A = A.Id`. Otherwise, I agree with this recommendation. I've seen this pattern quite often with many-to-many (A-C) joins defined using an intermediate junction table (B) - particularly if the distant table has additional conditionals applied.

Comment: The Paretheses are not necessary for correct execution, at least in this case.

Comment: I stand corrected. Each ON condition just picks up the two preceding pending join components. (Reminds me of RPN (Reverse Polish Notation) on my old HP-35 calculator.) I have just gotten into the habit of adding the parentheses anyway.

Answer (score -1):

As @jarlh wrote most people think LEFT to RIGHT as much more intuitive, so it's very confusing to see RIGHT joins in the code.
In this cases sometimes I found that SQL Server creates better query plans when I use OUTER APPLY in combination with WHERE EXISTS clauses, over your LEFT JOINs and inner INNER JOIN with WHERE EXISTS
The result is not much different of what you have in your first example:

```
SELECT A.Id, T.Id
FROM
            #A                                      AS A
OUTER APPLY ( 
    SELECT C.Id FROM #C AS C 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #B AS B WHERE A.Id = B.Id_a AND B.Id_C = C.Id)  )T;
```

Comment: This is not the same. Exists is a semijoin; if there were 10 rows in table B with identical id_a and id_c, your query would return 1 row, OP's would return 10.

Comment: While this is not exactly the same as the original, as @GeorgeMenoutis points out, it is a good suggestion that would work in many cases - I have tried it in one instance and it did indeed improve performance a bit, so definitely a useful example if not an exact answer.

Comment: It is so vastly different, a performance increase is expected. The semijoin operator will terminate at the first row it finds, versus scanning for more rows and potentially return them too.

Comment: As I wrote it depends on the case, in some cases I saw that it really uses semijoin with as many executions as rows in #a  (nature of OUTER APPLY). In other cases I got same execution plan as (LEFT JOIN together with INNER JOIN),